# What part of speech is "atom" in "hydrogen atom"?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, parts-of-speech

What is the type (adjective, noun, etc.) of the word *atom* in *hydrogen atom*?

I think that *atom* here does not qualify *hydrogen* in any way and we can use it or not, and the meaning of the word *hydrogen* will not change. So, *hydrogen atom* and *hydrogen* are equivalent.

Comment: They are both nouns.  *Hydrogen atom* is a compound noun.  The word *hydrogen* alone doesn't refer to a single atom but the element hydrogen in general.

Comment: Please do not vote to close this. It is a legitimate question. See the discussion Kosmonaut and I had on this very topic last year, referenced in my answer. The OP is not expressing the idea well, but I believe this is the point of the question.

Comment: +1 : This is an excellent question, the down/close votes are disheartening

Comment: You've got it backwards. In *hydrogen atom*, it's *hydrogen* that qualifies *atom*, not the other way round. We are not speaking French.

Comment: For scientific purposes it is sometimes necessary to distinguish between individual hydrogen atoms and the usual free form which is a diatmoic molecule.

Comment: @cindi: Calling this question "excellent" is quite a stretch. It shows no research effort whatsoever, and it is unclear what is actually being asked here, as the question actually consists of two completely unrelated ones ("what part of speech is X", and "are Y and Z equivalent"). Now hover over the downvote arrow to see what a downvote means: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". The downvotes are entirely justified.

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道 apologies : I was using "excellent" and "downvote" in their dictionary senses :-)

Comment: "Hydrogen" is functioning as an adjective to modify the noun "atom", i.e. to specify what kind of atom it is. "Hydrogen atom" and "atom" are not linguistically equivalent: It would be perfectly reasonable to talk about a "helium atom", etc, or to talk about atoms in general without reference to a particular element. Yes, IN CONTEXT the atom we are talking about is a hydrogen atom, so you could say the two are equivalent, but the whole point of language is that we use words to identify things. (continued)

Comment: (continued) If I say, "Sally is my wife", "Sally" and "wife" are referring to the same person, but that doesn't make the sentence pointless. The purpose of the sentence is to tell the reader that "Sally" and "my wife" are the same person. Likewise, "hydrogen" can also be a noun, so you could use the word "hyrdrogen" without saying "atom". But depending on the context, the word "atom" might tell the reader that we are talking about an individual atom, or that we are discussing atomic-level properties rather than information in some other context. "Hydrogen has one proton" (continued again)

Comment: (continued again) could be unclear: Do I mean each atom, or do I mean that hydrogen has a different kind of proton than other atoms, or that all hydrogen shares a single proton, etc? I could certainly talk about hydrogen without reference to atoms, like "Hydrogen costs $20 per liter" or "Hydrogen was known to the ancient Greeks".

Answer (score 7):

*Atom* is a noun. *Hydrogen atom* is a noun pair. It is a matter of debate whether the first word in a noun pair is an actual adjective, but it functions like one. Cf. *coat rack*, etc.

See the [discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/560162#560162) about this very matter, which @Kosmonaut and I had in chat last year.

**ADDENDUM**

Here is the discussion, minus the interwoven chat threads that are not germane to the issue:

> **Robusto**
>   Hey, @Kosmonaut, been meaning to ask you a question. Do noun pairs always subordinate one noun into adjectival status, or do they ever coexist as equal, independent nouns. In *The Marble Faun* it feels to me that marble serves as an adjective, but I don't quite feel that princess is completely adjectival in *The Princess Bride*. Any thoughts?
>
> **Kosmonaut**
>   In fact, I would say that those two words [*marble* and *faun*] are functioning as adjectives.
>   Even princess.
>
> **Robusto**
>   I know what you're saying, but if two states of being are coequal, or the one that comes first actually forms a more applicable noun (whatever that means; work with me here), can't noun pairs simply be appositive and not in an adjectival-nominal relationship?
>
> **Kosmonaut**
>   Noun pairs can certainly be in a noun-noun relationship, just not these two cases.
>   One way that often sheds light on this is the prosody of the phrase.
>
> **Robusto**
>   Can you give me some examples of legitimate noun-noun combos?
>
> **Kosmonaut**
>   poster board
>   hat rack
>
> **Robusto**
>   But doesn't "hat" get subordinated to "rack" in that combo?
>   A "hat rack" is a type of rack for holding hats.
>
> **Kosmonaut**
>   In adj+noun pairs, usually the primary stress falls on the noun. But in noun+noun pairs, the stress falls on the first noun.
>   I'm actually going by pure phonology/syntax to decide this — how they behave in the phrase, and not semantics.
>
> **Robusto**
>   Ahh, interesting distinction. Hence my confusion with "princess bride".
>
> **RegDwight**
>   The stress is on the princess.

[Note: I disagreed with @Reg on this, and still feel the stress is on "bride" in *The Princess Bride*, but that did not get entered into the text.]

> **Kosmonaut**
>   But, your followup question about which thing is central to the meaning, that's an interesting question unto itself.
>   I just wouldn't use that to determine the lexical category.

...

> **Kosmonaut**
>   Ah, you've seen The Adjective Noun!
>
> **Robusto**
>   No, but I've seen The Noun Noun.

Comment: +1 : it would be interesting if you could elaborate on that debate.

Comment: Well for me this is a noun enclosed in 2 words, and in German that is definitely going to be one word. And I don't like Noun pair, if there are three nouns what is it going to be - noun triplet? :D

Comment: @speedyGonzales Would adj+noun be one word in German?

Comment: @Kris: If they make it so. *Selbstbedienungsrestaurant* would be such a combo, I believe.

Comment: @Robusto初夢 Selbstbedienungsrestaurant ***is*** a word. Don't if 'they made it so'. :)

Comment: @Kris: It had to start somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

*Atom* is a countable noun.  *Hydrogen* is a mass noun.  *Hydrogen* does not have the same meaning as *hydrogen atom*.

*Hydrogen atom* is another way to say *atom of hydrogen* (just like *ice cube* is another way to say *cube of ice*).  You need to say *atom of hydrogen* (or *100 ml of hydrogen*, or something similar) because *hydrogen* is a mass noun.

So *atom (of)* **does** qualify *hydrogen*.

Comment: `Atom` doesn't qualify `hydrogen`, `hydrogen` qualifies `atom`.  It tells what kind of atom it is.

Comment: Besides not addressing the OP question, it is wrong. Hydrogen qualifies atom, and not the other way round.

Comment: I have used the term *qualify* in the sense that the OP used it.  In the OP's sense, atom certainly does qualify hydrogen, as in *atom of hydrogen* or *hydrogen atom*.  The OP's question was: what are the word classes of *atom* and *hydrogen*, and why can't I just say *a hydrogen*?  I have answered both those points.  However, I didn't clearly state the connection between *hydrogen atom* and *an atom of hydrogen*, so I've amended that now.

Comment: I see a difference between _fruit basket_, and _a basket of fruit_.

Comment: A fruit basket is a basket whose purpose is to hold fruit. Remove the fruit and it is still a fruit basket. The closest equivalent would be a "basket for fruit." A basket of fruit would refer to the quantity of fruit.

Comment: Good point about the distinction between fruit basket and basket of fruit, but I'm not sure that's helped much.  After thinking about this more, I see where the grammatical problem lies: atoms (or molecules) are the point at which the mass noun (12g of carbon) turns into something countable (6*10^23 carbon atoms).  I think my new example better reflects that idea.

Comment: After all the edits it was getting kind of messy, so I've rewritten it.  Does it pass muster now?